# Date and Time is OK on MySQL but it's shown a different data into PHP file

Tags: php, mysql

I have a remote DB (Hosted on Hostgator.com, with PHP 7.3 - MySQL 5.6.46 and PhpMyadmin 4.9.7) that saves the date and time of my order creation. When I open the MYSQL (using phpmyadmin) it shows the correct date and time, however, when opening my website the date and time are totally different from what is saved in the DB.

My DB has a table 'transactions' and a field named 'create', which is responsible for receiving the date/time from my query. And it has the following config: 'created` datetime NOT NULL'.

The problem is when I execute the command for insert the data into the table, for example: "INSERT INTO transaction (created) VALUES(NOW())"; then it correctly enters the current date and time. E.g.: 2021-07-23 16:35:56

The problem is that when I call the date it is wrong for me it displays: 07/15/2021 11:42:48

Every way I put it, even though the data is 2021-07-23 16:35:56 in the database it always returns to me 2021-07-15 11:42:48

My code to get the data:

```
$query_transaction = "SELECT * FROM transacoes where id_transacao = $transacao_id";
$result_transaction= mysqli_query($conn, $query_transaction);
$row_transaction = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_transaction);
$CreationDate = $row_transaction['created'];

echo "date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($CreationDate))"; => 15/07/2021 11:42:48

echo "date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($row_transacoes['created']))"; => 15/07/2021 11:42:48

echo $row_transacoes['created']; => 2021-07-23 11:42:48

echo $dataCriacao; => 2021-07-23 11:42:48
```

Comment: English only please.

Comment: Or you can move your question to https://pt.stackoverflow.com

Comment: what is database column type for column 'created' ? secondly, do u set datetimezone before echo date created ??

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `date_default_timezone_set()`